# 'Uniform differentiability'

Tags: calculus

I am working on a concept of uniform differentiability. f is uniformly differentiable on [a,b] if ∀ ε ∃ a δ such that |(f(x+h)-f(x))/h - f'(x)| < ε for all x in the interval when 0<|h|<δ. I am working on a theorem on it. If f has a continuous derivative on a closed interval, f is uniformly differentiable in that interval. I need a proof that doesn't use the mean value theorem. An elementary proof so to speak. By contradiction and utilizing Weierstrass's limit point theorem

Comment: [From this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240296/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-uniformly-differentiable?noredirect=1&lq=1) it seems like uniform differentiability is a known, but rarely used concept.

Comment: @NikolajPedersen And [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556707/a-function-is-uniformly-differentiable-if-its-derivative-is-uniformly-continuous/) says it's equivalent to a very commonly used concept.